# Print a List in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to do something as simple as this:

Print a list.

```
let a = [1;2;3;4;5]
```

How can I print this list to Standard Output?

Comment: What did you try?  Did you know about the `%a` format specification (for user defined printing) of `Printf.printf` ?

Comment: I just began learning OCaml. I tried the %d format specification. Actually i wasn't aware of the ';' that allows specifying more than one statement - like in the answer by ackar.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do this with a simple recursion :

```
let rec print_list = function 
[] -> ()
| e::l -> print_int e ; print_string " " ; print_list l
```

The head of the list is printed, then you do a recursive call on the tail of the list.

Comment: what is the significance of the empty parentheses on the second line?

Comment: @Noah_S `()` is the object of type `unit`, which I believe is the standard thing that's usually returned by a function to be executed only for side-effects.   Other printing functions such as `print_int` also have return type `unit`.  If you execute the `let` above, you'll see that `print_list` will have return type `unit`.  Something else could in principle be returned, e.g. `42`, or `"All done printing!"`, in which case the return type would be `int` or `string`, respectively.

Comment: since print_int is deprecated List.iter/List.map with printf is a better option.

Answer (score 70):

You should become familiar with the List.iter and List.map functions. They are essential for programming in OCaml. If you also get comfortable with the Printf module, you can then write:

```
open Printf
let a = [1;2;3;4;5]
let () = List.iter (printf "%d ") a
```

I open Printf in most of my code because I use the functions in it so often. Without that you would have to write `Printf.printf` in the last line. Also, if you're working in the toploop, don't forget to end the above statements with double semi-colons.

Comment: If you use the List module from Core (e.g. you are following Real World Ocaml) you need to do: `List.iter ~f:(printf "%d ") a`

Answer (score 34):

```
print_string (String.concat " " (List.map string_of_int list))
```

Answer (score 8):

If the question is about finding the quickiest way to implement this, for example when debugging, then we could say that:

- extended standard libraries (e.g. batteries) typically have some additional functions:

  ```
  List.print
    ~first:"[" ~sep:";" ~last:"]" (fun c x -> Printf.fprintf c "%d" x) stdout a
  ```
- this tiny [syntax extension](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/format/) that I wrote some time ago allows you to write:

  ```
  <:print<[$!i <- a${$d:i$}{;}]>>
  ```
- automatic generation is not immediately available (because of the lack of run-time type information in OCaml data representation) but can be achieved using either code generation from the types, or run-time types.

Answer (score 8):

I'm very late answering, but here's another way:

```
let print_list f lst =
  let rec print_elements = function
    | [] -> ()
    | h::t -> f h; print_string ";"; print_elements t
  in
  print_string "[";
  print_elements lst;
  print_string "]";;
```

To print an int list, we could write:

```
print_list print_int [3;6;78;5;2;34;7];;
```

However if we were going to do this a lot, it would save time to specialize the function using partial application:

```
let print_int_list = print_list print_int;;
```

Which we can now use like so:

```
print_int_list [3;6;78;5;2;34;7];;
```

What if we wanted to do something pretty complex, like printing an int list list? With this function, it's easy:

```
(* Option 1 *)
print_list (print_list print_int) [[3;6;78];[];[5];[2;34;7]];;

(* Option 2 *)
let print_int_list_list = print_list (print_list print_int);;
print_int_list_list [[3;6;78];[];[5];[2;34;7]];;

(* Option 3 *)
let print_int_list_list = print_list print_int_list;;
print_int_list_list [[3;6;78];[];[5];[2;34;7]];;
```

Printing an (int * string) list (i.e. a list of pairs of ints and strings):

```
(* Option 1 *)
print_list (fun (a, b) -> print_string "("; print_int a; print_string ", "; print_string b; print_string ")") [(1, "one"); (2, "two"); (3, "three")];;

(* Option 2 *)
let print_pair f g (a, b) =
  print_string "(";
  f a;
  print_string ", ";
  g b;
  print_string ")";;
print_list (print_pair print_int print_string) [(1, "one"); (2, "two"); (3, "three")];;

(* Option 3 *)
let print_pair f g (a, b) =
  print_string "(";
  f a;
  print_string ", ";
  g b;
  print_string ")";;
let print_int_string_pair = print_pair print_int print_string;;
print_list print_int_string_pair [(1, "one"); (2, "two"); (3, "three")];;

(* Option 4 *)
let print_pair f g (a, b) =
  print_string "(";
  f a;
  print_string ", ";
  g b;
  print_string ")";;
let print_int_string_pair = print_pair print_int print_string;;
let print_int_string_pair_list = print_list print_int_string_pair;;
print_int_string_pair_list [(1, "one"); (2, "two"); (3, "three")];;
```

Comment: Interesting, the only 'drawback' is there's always an additional `;` in the list. For example `[[4;2;];[2;];]`

Answer (score 4):

I would do this in the following way:

```
let a = [1;2;3;4;5];;
List.iter print_int a;;
```

Comment: should be `List.iter a print_int;;`

Comment: @nnyby https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/camlp4_3.10/foreach_tutorial.html says it should be `List.iter print_int a;;`

Comment: Oh okay - I'm using OCaml Core which has switched the syntax here: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Core_list  The type for List.iter in Core is `'a t -> f:('a -> unit) -> unit`

Comment: And to get rid of the "labels were omitted" warning you would do: `List.iter a ~f:print_int;;`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can decouple printing a list and turning a list into a string. The main advantage for doing this is that you can use this method to show lists in logs, export them to CSVs...

I often use a listHelper module, with the following :

```
(** Generic method to print the elements of a list *)
let string_of_list input_list string_of_element sep =
  let add a b = a^sep^(string_of_element b) in
  match input_list with
  | [] -> ""
  | h::t -> List.fold_left add (string_of_element h) t
```

So, if I wanted to output a list of floats to a csv file, I could just use the following :

```
let float_list_to_csv_row input_list = string_of_list input_list string_of_float ","
```

Comment: Might be more idiomatic if the list is the last argument the function takes.

Answer (score 2):

Just a solution with %a :

```
open Printf
let print_l outx l = 
     List.map string_of_int  l
  |> String.concat ";"
  |> fprintf outx "%s"
```

Test :

```
# printf "[%a]\n" print_l [1;2;3] ;;
[1;2;3]
- : unit = ()
# printf "[%a]\n" print_l [];;
[]
- : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let print_list l =
  let rec aux acc =
    match acc with
     | [] -> ()
     | x :: tl ->
       Printf.fprintf stdout "%i"; aux tl
   in aux l
```

Or

```
let sprintf_list l =
  let acc = ref "{" in
  List.iteri (fun i x ->
    acc := !acc ^
      if i <> 0
      then Printf.sprintf "; %i" x
      else Printf.sprintf "%i" x
  ) l;
  !acc ^ "}"

let print_list l =
  let output = sprintf_list l in
  Printf.fprintf stdout "%s\n" output
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line of code to the recursive function that I saw on this thread. Because, it was printing the element ";" for example, even for the last element. This is a very useful function because you can print almost any type of list (even list of list) with ease.

> | hd::[] -> f hd

```
let print_list f l =
  let rec print_elements = function
    | [] -> ()
    | hd::[] -> f hd 
    | hd::tl -> f hd; print_string ";"; print_elements tl
  in print_string "["; print_elements l; print_string "]";;
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing [first class modules](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/firstclassmodules.html) and the [`Format` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Format.html), we can now make a very flexible `list_to_string` (or call it `string_of_list` if you prefer) without writing a lot of code.

```
# let list_to_string 
      (type t) 
      (module M : Stringable with type t = t) 
      ?(sep = "; ") 
      (lst : t list) =
    let rec aux ppf = function
      | [] -> Format.fprintf ppf ""
      | [x] -> Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (M.to_string x)
      | x::xs -> Format.fprintf ppf "%s%s" (M.to_string x) sep; aux ppf xs
    in
    Format.asprintf "[%a]" aux lst;;
val list_to_string :
  (module Stringable with type t = 't) -> ?sep:string -> 't list -> string =
  <fun>
# module StringRep = struct
    type t = string
    let to_string s = Format.sprintf {|"%s"|} s
end;;
module StringRep : sig type t = string val to_string : t -> t end
# print_endline 
  @@ list_to_string (module StringRep) ~sep: ", " 
  @@ List.map string_of_int [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
- : unit = ()
# list_to_string (module Int) [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;
- : string = "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]"
```

It's also possible to modify this slightly to generalize it and make printing not require building an entire string first before printing it.

```
# let list_pp
      (type t)
      (module M : Stringable with type t = t)
      ?(sep="; ")
      ()
      ppf
      (lst : t list) =
    let rec aux ppf = function
      | [] -> ()
      | [x] -> Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (M.to_string x)
      | x::xs -> Format.fprintf ppf "%s%s" (M.to_string x) sep; aux ppf xs
    in
    Format.fprintf ppf "[%a]" aux lst;;
val list_pp :
  (module Stringable with type t = 't) ->
  ?sep:string -> unit -> Format.formatter -> 't list -> unit = <fun>
```

And then call:

```
# Format.printf "%a\n" (list_pp (module Int) ()) [1; 2; 3; 4];;
[1; 2; 3; 4]
- : unit = ()
```