# How to print a list of lists in OCaml

Tags: arrays, list, ocaml

Hello I am trying to print my list of list, but I cant I tried alot ways but I cant find a solution.

I tried to convert my list of list to an array, because I know how to print a array and I was using this function `let sll_to_saa sll = Array.of_list (List.map Array.of_list sll)` but it dont convert a list of list to a simple array. It convert to a `Array Array`.

Can someone Helpp mee? :D

Comment: For printing lists of lists of int: `let print_int_list_list = List.iter (List.iter (Printf.printf "%d "))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print a list : `let printlist l = List.iter (fun x -> print x) l`
To print a list of list : `List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) l`

About your function  sll_to_saa : it returns an array of array simply by definition.

If you wish to return a single array : may be you want to get an array of the concatenation of the list of list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can print a list (see, per example : [Print a List in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134929/print-a-list-in-ocaml)), you can turn a list of list into a list (using `concat` alias `flatten`) and the print the list.

```
val concat : 'a list list -> 'a list
Concatenate a list of lists. The elements of the argument are all concatenated together (in the same order) to give the result. Not tail-recursive (length of the argument + length of the longest sub-list).
```